# SQL Server Query column from Select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone please guide me what's wrong in this SQL Server query:

```
SELECT 
    A.*,
    (SELECT TOP 1 B.Name FROM B WHERE Contains(B.Name,A.Name)) Name 
FROM A;
```

It seems that `A.Name` is inaccessible in the query.

I want to populate a column in select query with data from another table. I can't use INNER JOIN since there isn't any FK relationship between tables.

Actually I want to insert data from `table A` into another `table C`, but for insert I need to populate a `NOT NULL Column` in `table C`, that I am trying to populate with this query `(SELECT TOP 1 B.Name FROM B WHERE Contains(B.Name,A.Name))` as column.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can use a join in T-SQL against any columns you want. If the B.Name and A.Name columns match, it doesn't matter if there is no foreign key.

Comment: Will it work in case of Full Text Search. And what if there are multiple matching rows in table B?

Comment: Is B full-text indexed?

Comment: I tried `SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON Contains(B.[Name],A.[Name]));` But even this doesn't work and complaints `Incorrect syntax near *A.* Expecting string TEXT_LEX or Variable`

Comment: Yes B is full text indexed.

Comment: is that the correct syntax for the first argument of CONTAINS?  The doc says just the column name (maybe as a string) rather than the column value.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `B.[Name]` is okay in `contains` but its complaining about `A.[Name]` its asking it to be a string or a variable name.

Comment: Looking at the context I think it wants just one value not a set of values, maybe you could get this to work using cross apply

Comment: As per my understanding `A.[Name]` should be a single value since its an Inner Join.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just as the error message explains. The second argument of CONTAINS must be a literal string or a variable. It’s not the case that everywhere a string is allowed in T-SQL that you can also use a column name.

You could do something kludgy like this, but performance would likely be abominable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DoesContain(@arg VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS tinyint AS BEGIN
  RETURN
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM B
      WHERE CONTAINS([Name],@arg)
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
END;
GO

SELECT
  A.*,
  (SELECT TOP 1 B.Name FROM B WHERE dbo.DoesContain(A.Name)=1) as [Name]
FROM A;
```